# Add rows to dataframe based on criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
percentDf <- data.frame(category=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d"), 
                        percent=c(50, 50, 100, 30, 70, 100))

percentDf
  category percent
1        a      50
2        a      50
3        b     100
4        c      30
5        c      70
6        d     100
```

In rows where the value in `percent` is 100, I need to replicate that row, and add it underneath. This should be the dataframe outputted:

```
percentDfComplete <- data.frame(category=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d"), 
                                percent=c(50, 50, 100, 100, 30, 70, 100, 100))

percentDfComplete
  category percent
1        a      50
2        a      50
3        b     100
4        b     100
5        c      30
6        c      70
7        d     100
8        d     100
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just pick them up first and then `rbind` them and them `order` them.

```
out <- rbind(percentDf, percentDf[percentDf$percent == 100, ])
out[order(out$category), ]
```

---

Alternatively, you can first find which rows have `percent = 100` and append and sort and index your data.frame.

```
percentDf[sort(c(seq_len(nrow(percentDf)), which(percentDf$percent == 100))), ]
```

Note: If you have in your original data.frame two rows with `b 100` then you'll get each of the rows duplicated here.

Comment: what if you want to preserve the category order?

Comment: @eddi, The second solution does exactly that, isn't it? Ex: if category=`d,c,c,b,a,a` and percent=`50,50,100,30,70,100`, then, second solution would give: `d,c,c,c,b,a,a,a` and `50,50,100,100,30,70,100,100`.